# retrieving tweets using Abraham/twitteroAuth cakephp 3

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth, cakephp-3.0, tweets

I'm trying to retrieve tweets using Abraham/twitteroAuth : https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth . this is my controller:

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;
use App\Controller\AppController;
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;
class TweetsController extends AppController
{
public function index()
{
  $oauth_access_token = 'XXXXXXXX';
  $oauth_access_token_secret = 'XXXXXXXX';
  $consumer_key = 'XXXXXXXXXX';
  $consumer_secret = 'XXXXXXXX';
  $connection = new TwitterOAuth($consumer_key,$consumer_secret,$oauth_access_token,$oauth_access_token_secret);
  $tweets = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=hello&count=5");
  $this->set('tweets', $tweets);
}}
```

And this is my view index.ctp:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Twitter search</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="tweets index large-10 medium-9 columns">
    <?php foreach ($tweets as $tweet): ?>
            <?php foreach ($tweet as $t): ?>
                <p><?= $t->text ?><br></p>; 
            <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

but i'm not getting any tweets. when i try debug($tweets); in my controller i get this :

```
object(stdClass) {
errors => [
    (int) 0 => object(stdClass) {
        message => 'Sorry, that page does not exist'
        code => (int) 34
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TwitterOAuth::get() only needs the path, not the full url, and parameters need to be given as an array, not a query string. Try this instead:

```
$tweets = $connection->get("search/tweets.json", ['q' => 'hello', 'count' => 5);
```

Review TwitterOAuth's source code to learn more: https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/blob/master/src/TwitterOAuth.php#L177